# Popup in Wicket (x-editable)

Tags: java, wicket, x-editable

can you tell me if it possible to create wicket popup with inputs for x-editable? I need create something like this:

http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html

but I am new in wicket. I looked for some components in wicket, but I found only modal. I need popup for editting not modal :/

Can you tell me how to do that if it possible, or where I can found some resources with samples? Thank you in advice.

Comment: We need more input in order to resolve this . If martin solution not work means you have to go with custom wicket component on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wicket-Bootstrap project provides integration with x-editable in its -extentions module. There is a demo as well.

See https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap

Comment: It looks there is a lot of coding when I don't want use this library :/

Comment: You can just copy paste the files from https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap/tree/wicket-7.x/bootstrap-extensions/src/main/java/de/agilecoders/wicket/extensions/markup/html/bootstrap/xeditable to your project. The licencing allows this!

Comment: I afraid this is not solution for me, this classes are depends on another classes and another are depends on another and so on .. I have to copy a lot of classes due to one popup.